# Flag Declined and How to avoid it

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged an "answer" in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283736/condition-for-short-exact-sequence-of-groups-to-be-isomorphic/283797#283797) as not being an answer. It seemed clear to me when I flagged the answer as not an answer, that the OP who didn't have an account was answering a question given in the comments. But my flag was declined because "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer". In cases like this should I flag it with other and include more of an explanation as to what I think is wrong rather than just flagging as not an answer?

Comment: I apologize. That was my mistake. I did not see that it was indeed an answer to one of the comments. Unfortunately, there is no way to undecline a flag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know who declined your flag. I converted the answer to a comment and merged the accounts. In general I think it's good to flag with more detail rather than less.

Comment: All right. In the future if I feel the need to "appeal" a declined flag what other methods do I have besides making a meta post?

Comment: Flag again? ${}$